# Bipartite matching

Tags: integer-programming, graphs, matching

If I have two matrix
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
2 & 3 
\end{bmatrix} $$ and $$B = \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 4 \\
5 & 3 
\end{bmatrix} $$

We have to make a matching between $A$ and $B$ such that the we achieve maximum weight is achieved, which is the sum of A and B, and that our matching is stable.

For instance, $$w = \begin{bmatrix}
4 & 6 \\
7 & 6 
\end{bmatrix} $$

Here $w$ is the weight matrix, and order to get max weights, taking rows of $w$ to be $a_1$ and $a_2$ and columns to be $b_1$ and $b_2$. We would have $a_1$ matches to $b_2$ and $a_2$ matches to $b_1$. However a stable matching is defined if there exists no blocking pair, that is, there does not exist any pair $i \in A$ and $j \in B$ that prefer each other to their current partners under the matching (preference is made according to cardinality of elements. And hence, $a_2$ would prefer to be matched to $b_2$, which is not the case here. I am not sure on how to solve this problem.

I have been able to compute maximum weight. I am sure this can be formulated as an IP, but not sure how to do so.

Comment: It is rather unclear what is being matched with what. Can you perhaps rephrase the question to clarify the underlying problem?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? You want a matching between the rows and columns of the matrices, right? The "goodness" of a matching is given by the sum of the corresponding entry in the weight matrix $w$, while the feasibility of a matching (apart from being a matching) is based on stability for which the preferences are given how? The number in the matrix $A$ for the row player and $B$ for the column player?

Comment: @ttnick: the goodness of the matching is indeed as you have defined. The question does indeed suggest that stability for preferences are based on the number in matrix $A$ and $B$ respectively. I am not entirely sure on the stability bit.

Comment: So in that case, $a_2$ prefers $b_2$ over $b_1$ because $A_{22} = 3 > 2 = A_{21}$. However that would not constitute a blocking pair (in the usual sense of the term) on its own. I guess that $b_2$ prefers $a_1$ as $B_{21} = 5 > 3 = B_{22}$, so that would make $(a_2, b_2)$ not a blocking pair since only one of those ($a_2$) wants to deviate.
However, I think there would be better (or more intuitive) ways to represent the input of the problem.

Comment: I think you are aksing about [this problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_of_stable_matchings#Weighted_stable_matching_and_closure).

Comment: @ttnick, indeed. But, I think my problem closely matches with Assignment problem with preference or the Gale Shapley's Algorithm. Both of which directly deal with preferences. Apologies for the delay in reply, I have been busy with somethings.